# Start New Activity with A button in android

Tags: android

i am new in android development, i would like to start a new activity when i click a button, but i try so long, and dint work, please any 1 help me.
Here is the Main Project.

```
package com.example.pdf;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout1);

        Button tut1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        tut1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent("com.example.pdf.main1"));
            }
        });

    }


}
```

Here is my Manifest

```
 <activity
            android:name="com.example.pdf.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <activity
            android:name="com.example.pdf.main1"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN1" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.Default" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

hi ,thx for all help, i already know the problem, And fix, thx for all help

Comment: post your manifest. no need for implicit intent. use explicit intent

Comment: @Raghunandan i already posted my manifest

Comment: @user3452735 remove intent filter for main1. use  `startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,main1.class));` and follow java naming convetions

Comment: As a learner, you should learn that `didn't work` is a useless statement.  What happens?  Your app crashed.  The wrong activity is launched.  Nothing happens. Your dog died.  The sun stopped shining?

Comment: @user3452735 also its it `main1` or `Main1`. case sensitive

Comment: @Simon when i click button, the apps force stop

Comment: @Raghunandan can u give me ur contact way? fb or any? i need help in adroid development

Comment: That's not how Stackoverflow works.  You post questions, other people post answers.  In the meantime, please post the stack trace from logcat.  That will tell use exactly what and where the problem is, but you need to work on the answers here first.

Comment: @simon ok, will try my best in programming, ty for your help

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
Intent I=new Intent(MainActivity.this,main1.class);
startActivity(I);
```

Comment: under public void onClick(View v)?

Comment: Yes, instead of your actual code in onClick

Comment: Yes instead of your code in onclick

Comment: @vyger can give me any contact way ? i need help in android develop

Comment: @zohreh can give me any way of contact? i need help in android develo

Comment: [http://www.freelancer.com/](http://www.freelancer.com/)